Best AI helper for FORM language
I am working in a topic which extensively requires symbolic computations. The previous code I have been provided is based on FORM. Unfortunately the documentation is not straightforward, and not a single AI tools (MS copilot, BBAI), I used so far can understand and help regarding FORM. Can you please suggest some tool which does understand and help in this language up to some extent?
As a simple check, I try to ask the following question to convert to FORM code:
set1 = {a1, b1, c1, d1};
set2 = {a2, b2, c2, d2};

If[SubsetQ[set1, {a1, b1}], Print["Yes"]]

but none passed so far

I guess LLMs do not have enough input data about FORM. For instance, how many StackOverflow questions exist about FORM?

What about ChatGPT 4o (Pro), extended  with the Wolfram Alpha GPT ?
Well, at this time I am a OpenAI Pro Customer.
This was my Prompt: Link to Chat
Transform this Mathematica code to FORM code, the symbolic manipulation language:

set1 = {a1, b1, c1, d1};
set2 = {a2, b2, c2, d2};

If[SubsetQ[set1, {a1, b1}], Print["Yes"]]

Answer:
* Define sets
S set1;
S set2;

* Elements of set1
a1 b1 c1 d1

* Elements of set2
a2 b2 c2 d2

* Check if a1 and b1 are in set1
#procedure check_subset(set)
  #do i = 1, `number_of_elements'
    if (match(`set'[i] == a1) && match(`set'[i] == b1)) {
      Print "Yes";
      #breakdo
    }
  #enddo
#endprocedure

* Call the procedure with set1
check_subset(set1)

No idea if this "good" code , or if it even is valid at all.
